# list out the missing words when compared file2 to file1

Tags: linux

i am looking for help for the below issue.

file1 has 2500 lines 
file2 has 500 lines

trying to list the words which are missing in file2 to compared to file1.

diff not working as these are huge files.
tried comm -12 ..not listed anything in the output.

thanks in advance.

Comment: One word per line?

Comment: yes, its like one word lines in both files.

Comment: Please provide an example of what the two files look like. You don't have to post the entirety of each file but just some of the lines so that there is a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: file1:
xxxxo_index_bin_primary 
xxxx_index_test_secondary_member
xxxx_bots_test_primary_pool

Comment: file 2: 
redfrog_bt
redfrog_bt_ 
redfrog_socr


these files has common words on similiar lines to above

Answer (score 1):

Without any performance consideration (could be improved if the lines are not unique):

```
grep -vxf file2 file1
```

Comment: i tried grep -vxVf .. did not gave me the output.. Let me try this..

Comment: @mytestresultsbackdidmy Why `-V`? But indeed I was missing the `-x`

Comment: i was checking the version to see if there is an issue..
without it , now i got something.. i will have to confirm with the list i got it correct or not.. 
thanks for helping on this..

Comment: if i add -x .. output writes all the matching whole lines.. 
i dont want it ,since i am looking for whats missing in file2 compared to file1. Your answer worked for me.
thank you.